An action on the space of connections on a $SO(3)$-vector bundle
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $E$ a smooth $SO(3)$-vector bundle over $M$ with fiberwise metric. Suppose there is an action of a finite cyclic group $\Bbb Z_n$ on $M$ by isometries, and there is also a $\Bbb Z_n$-action on $E$ by metric-compatible bundle maps covering the action on $M$. Now let $\mathfrak{C}$ be the space of all metric-compatible affine connections $\Omega^0(E)\to \Omega^1(E)$. I want to define a $\Bbb Z_n$-action on $\mathfrak{C}$ as follows:
First define a $\Bbb Z_n$-action on $\Omega^0(E)$ by letting $h\cdot \sigma:=h\circ\sigma\circ h^{-1}$, where $h^{-1}:M\to M$ and $h:E\to E$. Then define a $\Bbb Z_n$-action on $\mathfrak{C}$ which is determined by: $(h\cdot \nabla)_X(\sigma) = h\cdot (\nabla_X(h^{-1}\circ \sigma))$ for any vector field $X$ on $M$. (Here $\nabla_X(h^{-1}\circ \sigma)$ is viewed as an element of $\Omega^0(E)$.) But I'm not sure that this is well-defined, i.e. $h\cdot \nabla\in \mathfrak{C}$.
Note that the $\Bbb Z_n$-action on $\Omega^0(E)$ satisfies $h\cdot (f\sigma)=(f\circ h^{-1})(h\cdot \sigma)$ for $f\in C^\infty(M)$. It follows that $(h\cdot \nabla)_{fX}(\sigma)=(f\circ h^{-1})((h\cdot \nabla)_X(\sigma))$. But for a connection $\nabla$, $\nabla_X \sigma$ should be $C^\infty(M)$-linear in $X$. What went wrong?
P.S. This is actually a content in p.344 of this paper: https://bpb-us-e2.wpmucdn.com/faculty.sites.uci.edu/dist/3/246/files/2011/03/23_PseudoFreeOrbifolds.pdf

For clarity, I'm going to let $h:E\to E$ denote the transformation on the bundle, and $\check{h}:M\to M$ the corresponding transformation on $M$.
I would expect $h\cdot \nabla$ should be defined by
$$
(h\cdot\nabla)_X(\sigma) = h\cdot(\nabla_{\check{h}^*X}(h^{-1}\cdot \sigma))
$$
instead (the difference being the transformation of the vector field $X$). From this definition, it follows that
$$
(h\cdot \nabla)_{fX}(\sigma) = h\cdot(\nabla_{\check{h}^*(fX)}(h^{-1}\cdot\sigma)) = h\cdot((\check{h}^*f)\nabla_{\check{h}^*X}(h^{-1}\cdot \sigma)) = f (h\cdot\nabla)_{X}(\sigma)
$$
as required. I suspect the equation in the paper you linked just has a typo.

Does $\check{h}^*X$ mean $(\check{h}^*X)(p)=(d\check{h}^{-1} )(X(\check{h}(p)))$? If it is, then it seems that the adjusted definition of $h\cdot \nabla$ still has a problem with the Leibniz rule

Yes, that's what it means. I don't think there's any problem with the Leibniz rule - it follows pretty easily from $h\cdot(f\sigma) = (\check{h}^*f)(h\cdot\sigma)$ (unless I'm missing something?)

Oh you're right, I had a mistake in calculation. Thanks a lot!
